# Find minimal parameter when BVP for the LoDestro ODE has eigenvalue

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I am working on the problem of plasma stability in mirror traps (also called open traps). It leads to the LoDesctro second order ordinary differentional equation. In the most simple case of isotropic  plasma with steep-wise radial pressure profile it reads
\begin{multline*}
    0 =
    (\Lambda-1) \frac{d^{2}\phi}{dz^{2}}
    +
    \frac{d}{dz}
    2\left(
        1 - \frac{p}{B_{v}^{2}}
    \right)
    \frac{d\phi}{dz}
    \\
    +
    \phi
    \left[
        - \frac{d}{dz}\left(
            -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1-2p/B_{v}^{2})'}{1-2p/B_{v}^{2}}
        \right)
        \left(
            1 - \frac{p}{B_{v}^{2}}
        \right)
    \right.
    \\
    \left.
    -
    \frac{2p}{B_{v}^{2}}\frac{a_{v}''}{a_{v}}
    \right.
    \\
    \left.
    -
    \frac{1}{2}\left(
            -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1-2p/B_{v}^{2})'}{1-2p/B_{v}^{2}}
    \right)^{2}
    \left(
        1 - \frac{p}{B_{v}^{2}}
    \right)
    \right],
    \end{multline*}
where the prime $(')$ stands for $d/dz$, $a_v(z)=\sqrt{2/B_v(z)}$ is the plasma columb vacuum radius, and $B_v(z)$ is the vacuum magnetic field on the trap axis, for example,

\begin{equation*}
B_{v}(z) = 1 + (K-1)\sin^{2}(\pi z/2)
\end{equation*}

with $K$ being the mirror ratio, e.g. $K=8$. The LoDestro equation should be supplemented with the boundary conditions

\begin{equation*}
\phi'(0) = 0,
\qquad
\phi(0) = 1,
\qquad
\phi'(1) = 0,
\end{equation*}
to compute eigen value of the plasma pressure $p$ at given parameter
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda = \frac
{
    r_{w}^{2} + a^{2}
}{
    r_{w}^{2} - a^{2}
}.
\end{equation*}
It relates radius $r_w$ of conducting plasma chamber to plasma radius $a$. In the case under consideration parameter $\Lambda$ is a constant in the range from $\Lambda=1$ to $\Lambda=\infty$.  From physical point of view paramter $p$ can vary from $p=0$ to $p=1/2$. Note that the LoDestro euation becomes singular at the point $z=0$ as $p\to 1/2$. Numerical solution https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08376 reveals that no eigen value of $p$ is found at $\Lambda=1$ as it should be from physical reasoning. However, contrary to our expectations, eigenvalues close to $p=1/2$ were found with $\Lambda$ values as close to $1$ as possible, as close as our numerical code allows, for example, $\Lambda=1.0001$.

This fact seems surprising, since it means that the conducting wall stabilizes the plasma instability even if the vacuum gap between the plasma and the wall tends to infinity.

**Is it possible to prove that the eigenvalues of $p$ do not exist only if $\Lambda=1$ exactly?**

I tried to develop something similar to variational principle for this problem by multiplying the LoDestro equation by $2\phi$ and integrating by parts. It yields

\begin{multline*}
 0 =
2(\Lambda-1)
\int_0^1 d{z}
\phi'^{2}
+
\\
+
\int_0^1 d{z}
\left(
    1 - \frac{p}{B_{v}^{2}}
\right)
\left(
    2\phi'
    +
    \phi
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{(1-2p/B_{v}^{2})'}{1-2p/B_{v}^{2}}
\right)^{2}
+
\\
+
\int_0^1 d{z}
\phi^{2}
\left[
\frac{4p}{B_{v}^{2}}\frac{a_{v}''}{a_{v}}
\right]
.
\end{multline*}
Here first two integrals are positive, and the last one is negative. Numerical integration showed that second integral is small and cannot compensate the last one. So, the first integral is required, but it has the factor $(\Lambda-1)$ which disappear if $\Lambda\to1$.